# How to use nanopb over gsm modem communication where specific characters like CTRL+Z are used as msg termination in AT commands?

Tags: embedded, mqtt, nanopb

While looking for serialization-deserialization options, I came across nanopb meant for 32 bit controllers which use google protocol buffers.

As I got curious about trying this out for an mqtt communication on a gsm modem, I realized that there is no way I could let the nanopb’s encoding mechanism know how to treat escape characters/special characters such as CTRL+Z because they all get encoded in a hex format. (Eg; CTRL+Z in hex would be 0x1A) and gsm modems use 0x1A as a message termination character. Hence when sending a nanopb encoded message via AT commands to a modem, the modem interprets the encoded message containing 0x1A as CTRL+Z which it should not.

Would it be possible to use nanopb in that case? Or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Ctrl-Z is 0x1A, not 0x0A, in most encodings.

Comment: True, it was my typo mistake.

Comment: Well, I know nothing about GSM modems, but: Don't they provide any escaping?

Comment: I doubt that the CTRL-Z is being "encoded in hex format" but rather simply being inserted as a CTRL-Z which has character code 0x1A - that is not the same thing.  Encoding in hex format would imply a string `"0x1A"` whereas is it not the case that the character `00011010b` is being inserted?   It is unclear to me what you are asking since in one place you state _"gsm modems use 0x1A as a message termination character"_, and later _"the modem interprets the encoded message containing 0x1A as CTRL+Z which it should not"_ - which contradicts the first statement 0x1A _is_ CTRL-Z.

Comment: This has not so much to do with nanopb as with how you pack the message data (nanopb output) and send it over the protocol you have.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very common problem with modems, and will apply to any binary data. All modems have a way of transferring binary data, but the method can vary between modem models.

Most common methods are:

- Using two UARTs, one for commands and one for data.
- Switching between [command and data mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_and_Data_modes_(modem)) using AT commands and escape sequence. Usually with `ATD` or `ATO` to switch to data mode, and then pause-`+++`-pause to switch back to command mode. The use of a pause in the escape sequence prevents `+++` occurring in other data from causing problems, but slows down the transfer.
- Using a separate signal wire (usually `DTR`) to switch between command and data mode.
- Escaping binary characters with a prefix, such as `DLE` = `0x10` character, which then alters the meaning of the following characters.

Your modem most likely supports at least one and probably multiple of these methods, but you'll need to check its manual on how to configure it.